# Is the magic number important

Tags: static-analysis, pe

While checking the PE header of DLLs and EXE(s) by PEviewer, I found  something called "*magic number*".

After googling "*magic number*". I found that it is used to determine the file type. My question is how can a malware analysist benefits from this magic number ? And why is it in the PE header ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *magic number* is a set of bytes used when accessing a file to determine its type. For example, the standard Microsoft PE begins with (in ASCII) `MZ`, the initials of one of the developers of MS-DOS.

The initial headers in a portable executable specify a variety of information regarding the file, ranging from the supported platform, number of symbols, number of sections, time stamps, etc. As such, it is a logical location to store the magic number, as it is also part of the file metadata.

> How can a malware analyst benefit from this magic number?

The only information the magic number provides is the file type, and as such that is all that can be garnered by a malware analyst, or any type of analysis. Although one can refer to the file extension to check a file type, they can be changed without affecting the contents of the file. As such, checking the magic number is a method to determine the true file type. Discrepancies would then indicate potential malicious behavior or attempts to hide data.

Comment: Could you provide me with the magic number of other populer file type of malware

Comment: @Ahmed: Wikipedia has a list of many: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures.

Comment: @Ahmed: you got it the wrong way around. *Malware* doesn't have a "magic number". Their *containers* do. Malware can be hidden inside executables, but also in PDFs, JPEGs, and even DOS batch files.

Comment: @Ahmed: Yes, don't confuse file types with malware. The file types serve as a way of storing malicious code.